# UTF-8 decoding error in PHP

Tags: php, html, utf-8, string-decoding

My database value is `Ã‰cole Polytechnique FÃ©dÃ©rale de Lausanne`. I cannot convert to html characters. I tried to convert using following method,

```
echo html_entity_decode(Ã‰cole Polytechnique FÃ©dÃ©rale de Lausanne');
echo html_entity_decode($Event['Event_speaker']);
```

Ist statement i got the actual result and the second one display exactly same as db value.

In my header am using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Can someone help??

Comment: There are no HTML entities in your string. Why do you call html_entity_decode?

Comment: *"the second one display exactly same as db value"* – Alright, then you're correctly outputting what is in your database, that's good. The problem is that you have garbage in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this PHP [predefined function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

```
<?php
$str = "Ã‰cole Polytechnique FÃ©dÃ©rale de Lausanne";
echo iconv_mime_decode($str);
```

Comment: That's not MIME encoding.